# Filter the values from the source in merge query in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have the **tableA** with **Key1**,**datetime** columns when I use merge query to insert I have get the duplicate rows in source.
 How can we filer the source inside the query by datetime has maximum

```
MERGE tableA AS t
USING (VALUES 
        ('datakeyA1', 'datetime value'), 
        ('datakeyB1', 'datetime value'),
        ('datakeyA1', 'max datetime value')
    ) AS s (Key1, datetime)
        ON s.Key1 = t.Key1
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET    Val = s.datetime
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Key1, datetime)
    VALUES (s.Key1, s.datetime);
```

When run the above query I get the:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once.

Is there any way to query only these rows ('**datakeyB1**', '**datetime** **value**'),('**datakeyA1**', '**max datetime value**') from all the values without using the intermediate table?

Expected results only insert/update the **datakeyB1**,**datakeyA1** values. If the date is same in both the data get only one row.

```
MERGE tableA AS t
USING (VALUES
        ('datakeyB1', 'datetime value'),
        ('datakeyA1', 'max datetime value')
    ) AS s (Key1, datetime)
        ON s.Key1 = t.Key1
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET    Val = s.datetime
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Key1, datetime)
    VALUES (s.Key1, s.datetime);
```

Comment: Your key is not a key? Thats why you update more than one......

Comment: Provide some logical code in your using statement instead of hardcoded values. You can just do a row_number() over(partition by key order by datetime desc) and select rows that are equal to 1. Then you will get distinct values and only 1 per key.

Comment: I have generated the values in the using statement via php code. I am trying this for multiple insert. If the **Key1** already exist I have to update that row for the key

Comment: I can see that. But if you get multiple same keys. Then you should adjust your php code.

Comment: Yeah I am also trying that meantime I am checking Is there any possibilities in sql. This optimize my code more fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `values` clause with a select statement, using `top 1 with ties` and `order by row_number...` - like this:

```
MERGE tableA AS t
USING (
        SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
        FROM
            (VALUES 
                ('datakeyA1', 'datetime value'), 
                ('datakeyB1', 'datetime value'),
                ('datakeyA1', 'max datetime value')
            ) AS s (Key1, datetime)
        ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY datetime DESC)
        ) s
        ON s.Key1 = t.Key1
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET    Val = s.datetime
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (Key1, datetime)
    VALUES (s.Key1, s.datetime);
```